# Encoding issue in Mailchimp emails

Tags: html, encoding, utf-8, gmail, mailchimp

I created a Mailchimp template for the email newsletter of the company I work for. There's an issue with some links and I can't work out how to fix them.

I add a link into the email like so:

```
<a href="http://www.nameofcompany.com/contact-us.php" target="_blank">Contact Us</a>
```

And the link appears fine, but when clicked within Gmail it takes you to the site's 404 page, even though the URL is (on the surface) correct.

After clicking the link, the URL displayed in the address bar is http://www.nameofcompany.com/contact-us.php, which is the correct URL and which when typed into the address bar directly goes to the correct page. But when I visit this URL from the email, then copy and paste it from the address bar into a new email in Gmail, I see: http://www.nameofcompany.com/contact%E2%80%90us.php

So this appears to be an issue with character encoding. I have no idea how to fix it though.

Here's the doctype, charset etc from the HTML of the email.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
```

The strangest thing is, most URLs in the email work perfectly fine, even those with dashes in.

What's causing this issue and how can I fix it?

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, fixed it. I found the template on Mailchimp and used "Edit this template's code" to edit the HTML within my browser. Then I found the  tag that was causing the trouble, deleted it and typed it back out again. Bit of a crude fix and I'm not sure why the problem originally arose but it's done the job!

Comment: Hi, I've got almost the same problem. Which tag was causing that issue?

Comment: Can't remember now, probably the `<a>` tag that had the incorrect URL.

Answer (score 0):

E2 80 90 is the Unicode byte sequence for the multibyte hyphen character and you should be using the ASCII one.
Which app. do you use for coding your html files? This has to do with the encoding of the hyphen. Try using a simple text font if you are given such option at your code editor (such as Courier).

Comment: I've been using TextWrangler. Been using the default font there (Monaco) but I'll try saving it as Courier and seeing if it makes a difference.

Not sure why this would be the issue as I've been using TextWrangler for all kinds of different stuff for months now and have never had a problem like this before.

Comment: does it happen only with Gmail or with other popular webmail services as well?

Comment: This didn't work but I've fixed it now. Thanks for your help anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why hyphen was encoded into 3 bytes here - usually non alpha/num characters in URL are encoded into one byte.

Try replacing hyphen with %2D, so that hyphen won't be transformed into %E2%80%90.